# Algorithm for searching string with wildcards

Tags: algorithms, strings, string-matching

I'm trying to find efficient algorithm for checking if string with wildcards contains given substring.

The parts of the string are separated with a "." character.

So for example I have

`ab.cd.*.efg`

And I want to check for given strings, if they are substrings of string above, for example to match with those:

```
ab
b.c
cd.qq <- "qq" is replacement for wildcard
d.qwe.ef <- "qwe" is replacement for wildcard
```

What is the best algorithm to use?